# lighttpd: redirecting to another page causes duplicated hostname in path

Tags: java, linux, redirect, proxy, youtrack

I've set up the `youtrack` distribution on my new centos server.
It runs on 8112 port, and I want to be able to open it only when I'm requesting a subdomain address.

So i've installed lighttpd, then I went to `lighttpd.conf` and added few lines of code there:

```
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "^subdomain\." {
        server.name   = "subdomain.example.com"
        proxy.server  = ( "" =>
                          ( "subdomain.example.com" =>
                                (
                                     "host" => "11.11.11.11",
                                     "port" => 8112
                                )
                          )
                         )
}
```

So now when I point subdomain.example.com to my browser, youtrack understands that I have not session yet and redirecting me in strange way to the /login page, then the address bar starts to look like

`subdomain.example.com/subdomain.example.com/login`

I've just read up bunch of internet pages about all that forwarding, redirecting, proxy stuff but I've not found anywhere anything about possible problems with that kind of `duplication` the hostname into a path...

I gave up and just put it here ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTrack redirects to login page using its baseURL. Try to change YouTrack's baseURL on Administration -> Settings page